# How can I bind configuration from a ServerConfig block in Ratpack groovy?

Tags: groovy, ratpack

I am trying to merge server and database configuration using the `ServerConfig` block in ratpack.groovy but `postgresConfig` is null when trying to create the datasource.

**PostgresConfig.groovy**

```
@Compile Static
class PostgresConfig {
    String user
    String password
    String serverName
    String databaseName
    Integer portNumber
}
```

**PostgresModule.groovy**

```
@CompileStatic
class PostgresModule extends ConfigurableModule<PostgresConfig> {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    @Provides
    DataSource dataSource(final PostgresConfig config) {
        createDataSource(config)
    }

    protected DataSource createDataSource(final PostgresConfig config) {
        new PgSimpleDataSource(
            user:         config.user,
            password:     config.password,
            serverName:   config.serverName,
            databaseName: config.databaseName,
            portNumber:   config.portNumber
        )
    }
}
```

**ratpack.groovy**

```
ratpack {
    serverConfig {
        props([
            'postgres.user':         'username',
            'postgres.password':     'password',
            'postgres.serverName':   'localhost',
            'postgres.databaseName': 'postgres',
            'postgres.portNumber':   5432
        ] as Map<String, String>)
        yaml "config.yaml"
        env()
        sysProps()
        require("/postgres", PostgresConfig)
    }
    bindings {
        PostgresConfig postgresConfig
        module HikariModule, { HikariConfig config ->
            config.dataSource = new PostgresModule().dataSource(postgresConfig)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `bindings` block you can reference the `serverConfig` configuration and so get a configured `PostgresConfig`. In your use case you don't need the `require("/postgres", PostgresConfig)` statement.

You could make the `PostgresModule` class not extend `ConfigurableModule`, because it is not used as a module.

```
ratpack {
    serverConfig { ... }
    bindings {
        module HikariModule, { HikariConfig config ->
            config.dataSource = new PostgresModule().dataSource(serverConfig.get("/postgres", PostgresConfig)
        }
    }
}
```